# How do I change the cursor used when the mouse pointer is over a QwtPlot?

Tags: qt, qwt

By default, the cursor changes to a crosshair when it’s within a QwtPlot on the screen. Calling

```
setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
```

from within my QwtPlot subclass doesn’t have any effect. How can I change this cursor to something other than a crosshair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `setCursor` on the plot’s *canvas*. From a QwtPlot subclass, for example,

```
canvas()->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
```